# Numpy, vectorizing selection of rows that meet buy/sell logic in quantitative analysis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, quantitative-finance

EDIT2:
Thanks for the replies, I have gotten further with:

buyChange = np.where(np.diff(buy>0)!=0)

sellChange = np.where(np.diff(sell>0)!=0)

Now I have 2 arrays of indexes, one where the buy Logic crosses over and one where the sell logic crosses over:

buy:(array([   3,    5,    8,    9,   14,   15,   17,   19,   20,   26,   27,
         33,   39,   41,   46,   47,   51,   60,   61,   62,   70,   71,
         75,   76,   77,   78,   80,   81,   83,   88,   90,   97,  100...

sell:(array([  22,   34,   54,   63,   85,   88,   89,  102,  103,  110,  111...

What I need now is pairs of indexes that represent the buy and sell pairs.  When the buy crosses over that is the start of a pair, and then the first higher number to that in the sell array is the second in that buy/sell pair.  Then the next highest in the buy array above the last sell is the start of the next pair.  For the above arrays it would be (3,22)(26,34)(39,54)(60,63)(70,85)(88,89).  I can then use those indexes in this code to find the corresponding open prices that I'll trade on in the back-test:

price = o[buyChange[0][index]+2]

\EDIT2

Edit:
I have found this function that finds the sections that are negative in the array, but now I have to find the day at the beginning of that section, the day where the array turned from positive to negative.  Can anyone help with that?

**`buys =  np.where( buy < 0 )`**

Something like the below doesn't work but it's the idea of what I want to implement:

**`buys =  np.where( buy < 0 and buy[-1] > 0 )`**

or:

**`buys =  np.where( buy[1:] < 0 and buy[:-1] > 0 )`**

/EDIT

I have a for loop that is going though arrays from a stock file and if statements that determine if a certain line is a buy or sell. I am looking for a way to vectorize this action, possibly to create a list of just the buy/sell days that I can then calculate my returns on.  Actually a list of the days after the signal days because I trade on open the next day. Here is the bones of my program:

```js
for stock in files:
  d,c,h,l,o,v = getData(str(root+'\\'+stock)) # creates numpy arrays of columns in file
  s = sma(c,SMA,stockLen)                     # creates array of simple moving average
  sL = sma(c,longSMA,stockLen)                # creates array of longer simple moving average
  
  #below is code that i'm trying to replace with vectorization:
  for day in range(stockLen):
    if c[day] < s[day] and stance == 'none':
      stance = 'holding'
      buyPrice = o[day+1]
    
    if c[day] > sL[day] and stance == 'holding':
      sellPrice = o[day+1]
      tradeProfit = pctChange(buyPrice,sellPrice)
      pctPerYear.append((250/holdingTime)*tradeProfit)
      stance = 'none'
```

I have gotten to the point of having 2 arrays, buy goes negative when I want to buy and sell goes positive when I want to sell, but I don't know how to put 'if statement' logic into the array without using an inefficient for loop.

here are the buy/sell arrays:

```js
buy  = c[:]-s[:]  #creates array that goes negative when closing price is below sma.
sell = c[:]-sL[:] #creates array that goes positive when closing price is above long sma.
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

EDIT:
Here is a snippet of data, its `date,close,high,low,open,volume`.  About 2500 rows per stock.

```
date,close,high,low,open,volume
20110718,43.40,43.68,42.93,43.07,25844
20110719,42.65,43.37,42.38,43.37,32334
20110720,43.11,43.11,42.06,42.46,22072
20110721,43.25,43.60,43.06,43.28,24965
```

Answer (score 0):

check out this link from Pandas documentation.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html

You may also find this link useful in the short term:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

For the code in above, have you tried to implement a vetorisation in the form:

```
DATA['Return'] = np.log(DATA['close'] / DATA['close'].shift(1))
```

Comment: happy to try to assist further if you can provide some data examples.

Comment: I added the data snippet.  Thanx for the pandas link, I'll look into using pandas with cython, the documentation says that it works fast on for loops so that might be the right solution rather than trying to eliminate this last for loop.

Comment: What duration in days are you using for you moving averages? (I am trying to complete this using LLOY.L data from 01-Jan-2015 to 06-Nov-2015 will that be enough data for the exercise? (221 days)

How do you derive holding time? (is it actual or derived by sell signal?

Are you looking to also create log Returns?

Comment: I'm trying to make the program that I learned from this tutorial more efficient.(vid 33) [link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcR-u9O8LyLR7URiKuW-XZq) For testing right now I'm using 5 and 15 SMA's, but this probably isn't a good algorithm to trade on, I'm just trying to get the basics working so I can modify and tweak it. I get the holding time with a line "if stance == 'holding': holdingTime += 1. I don't know exactly what a log return is, but I'm getting percent profit, appending it to a list, and sum(list)/len(list) after all the stocks have run. – puzzler 30 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find the points where a vector changes sign, you can do something like this:

```
change_points = np.where(np.diff(buy>0)!=0)
```